# Create mongodb collection from documents with non-staticly named parents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, mongodb-query

I have data that I have downloaded from a site I do not have control over and I'm having trouble parsing their data with MongoDB to trim the data into more manageable pieces.

The structure resembles this:

```
"data": { ..., "person": { "ID0001": { "id": 0001, ... }, ... }, ...}
```

I want to be able to have just the inner most data as the top level of my collection but I don't know how to strip off the "ID0001" level. Is there a way to do this in MongoDB or will I have to do it manually parsing the json data in JS?

Thanks.

Comment: *"I have data that I have downloaded from a site I do not have control over"*. Of course you have control over it, it's **you** who downloaded it. Nobody is forcing you to store it in exactly the same format in which you read it. If you want it in a different format to query, then simply "transform the data" as you write it. That is called "complete control". Please don't use the "have no control" excuse. That immediately sounds like you actually asked the question before and were told to change the structure. That is of course the "best thing to do".

Comment: I wasn't trying to pass this off as an excuse hence the part about manually parsing the data I was just wondering if there was a quicker way to do it through currently written mongo functions. I figured as much though. Thanks for your help.